# How to make identifyer for jQuery slide.Toggle function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make an identifyer for the jQuery slide.Toggle function. I am running a loop in php to print values, and these all have a button and a div which should be able to slide.Toggle.

What i have tried so far, but without luck, in the php:

```
<?php $rooms_array = sizeof($rooms) - 1;
    for ($i = 0; $i <= $rooms_array; $i++) { ?>

    <div style="margin-left:6px;" id="show_more<?php echo $i + 1; ?>">Foo Button</div>
    <div id="more_room_info<?php echo $i + 1; ?>" class="meetingroomInfoHide">
    <?php echo $rooms[$i]['description'] ?>
    </div>

<?php } ?>
```

The jQuery:

```
$('#show_more' + 1).click(function(){
    $('#more_room_info' + 1).stop().slideToggle('slow'); 
    return false;
});
```

So the above code works, but only for the first div which is created by the loop. This is because of the "+ 1" identifyer. I have tried to run er 'for'-loop, but this will not work, as i need the 'for'-loop to be outside the click function, and then the code won't run the code, as it just runs the for-loop when the page is loaded.

Where I am having trouble is in the jQuery. How do i make the "#show_more" be "#show_more1", and "#more_room_info" be "#more_room_info1", with a loop of some sort?

I could technically just make the code 50 times, and change the "+ 1", but this won't be nice.

Regards,
Patrick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, i found the solution after some different tries.
For anybody who finds themselves in the same problem, here is my solution.

The jQuery

```
function initialise() {

for (var i = 1; i < 20; i++) {
meetingroomInfo(i);
}

}

function meetingroomInfo(roomId) {

    $('#show_more' + roomId).click(function(){
        $('#more_room_info' + roomId).stop().slideToggle('slow'); 
        return false;
           // var not_hide = document.getElementById("more_room_info");
           // not_hide.className = not_hide.className - "meetingroomInfoHide";
    });
}
```